# Why JavaScript hoisting behave like this?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I just don't understand the reason behind hoisting.

```
var a = 10;

function test() {
    alert(a);
    var a = 20;
}
```

I am getting undefined as the value of a due to JavaScript hoisting.
Any specific reason behind putting all the declaration at the top.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to use two different vars with the same name in one scope?

Comment: the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) would explain it for you. Not sure if it's sufficient enough.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just declare your variables first, then move on with your life. There are much better things to worry about. Anyway, there are dozens of answers on SO on this topic, please search for them.

Comment: var a = 10; is private variable outside of test function and after calling test function, in statement alert(a),  a is undefined because a is private not public/global. and again you are declaring and assigning  var a which is private for test function. I think you want to access both private variable. so just make global by removing "var" from variable "a".

Comment: [Two words about "hoisting"](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-4-two-words-about-hoisting/)